# 'sqlite3.dll was not loaded' when trying to install GitHub

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I am trying to install GitHub using GitHubSetup.exe, downloaded from windows.github.com. The setup program 'downloads' what it needs, then closes and does nothing more.

Looking at TheLog.txt (in AppData/GitHub) shows the following:

```
2015-04-09 12:18:24.0747|ERROR|thread: 1|CrashManager|Dumping Loaded Module List
2015-04-09 12:18:24.0325|ERROR|thread: 1|CrashManager|Aieeeeeeee!
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'NativeMethods' threw an exception. ---> System.Exception: sqlite3.dll was not loaded.
   at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider.NativeMethods..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider.NativeMethods.sqlite3_open_v2(Byte[] filename, IntPtr& db, Int32 flags, Byte[] vfs)
at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider.SQLitePCL.ISQLite3Provider.sqlite3_open_v2(String filename, IntPtr& db, Int32 flags, String vfs)
   at Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String databasePath, SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks)
   at Akavache.Sqlite3.Internal.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String databasePath, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks)
at Akavache.Sqlite3.SQLitePersistentBlobCache..ctor(String databaseFile, IScheduler scheduler)
   at GitHub.Helpers.SqlitePersistentBlobCacheFactory.CreateBlobCache(String path)
   at GitHub.Helpers.SharedCache.<>c__DisplayClass5.<.ctor>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at GitHub.Helpers.SharedCache.get_LocalMachine()
   at GitHub.Helpers.AppLogManager.get_AnonymousIdentifier()
   at GitHub.Helpers.HaystackTarget.Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
   at NLog.Targets.Target.Write(AsyncLogEventInfo logEvent)
2015-04-09 12:18:24.0747|ERROR|thread: 1|CrashManager|Inner Exception
System.Exception: sqlite3.dll was not loaded.
   at SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider.NativeMethods..cctor()
```

'sqlite3.dll was not loaded.' is also the error I get when I try to click on the GitHib shortcut that is placed on the desktop.

I am running Windows 8.1, 64 bit.

I have tried downloading a sqlite3.dll file and placing it in system32, but that does nothing. I have also explicitly told my firewall to allow connections for the setup program. I feel a little in over my head here - does anyone have any suggestions?

Please let me know if I need to provide any more information!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Brendan here, one of the GitHub for Windows developers.

The latest update introduced a dependency that required a version of the Visual C++ Redistributable that wasn't installed as a pre-requisite. As a workaround, you can install the 32-bit version from here which adds it back in:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679